# Why Setupper created by Publish feature does not copy files to c:/PROGRAM FILES

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have VB project and I tried to use PUBLISH feature.

It seems to create nicely some kind of setup program, but the setup program does not ask where to copy files (it does not seem to copy filesto target machine "PROGRAM FILES".)

Is this setup program somehow different from usual installers?
NOTE: I want that app files are installed to Hard disk( from USB stick source)

Is the signing recommended or necessary?  My App is pretty simple, its just using access DB + printer api, should I still sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Publish" feature creates a [ClickOnce installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx). Such applications are installed per-user instead of per-machine, i.e., they are installed somewhere into the user's profile. [This is by design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) and has the advantage that the user installing the software does not need administrative privileges on the machine.

You can also create a setup project by going to `File/New/Project/Other Project Types/Setup and Deployment/Setup Project`. This creates a "conventional" MSI-based installer, offering the "classic" C:\Program Files type of installation.

On MSDN, two approaches are compared [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Our biggest problem in-house is privleges.
Does the "user" have access to write to "Program Files"?